# Getting long string that contains & in it from URL

Tags: javascript

So I wanna be able to seperate a long string from URL in my nodejs express server, because this is used for a project, you would upload code via URL parameter. Example being:

`www.example.com/bot/upload?code=function uuidv4() { return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); }); } console.log(uuidv4())`

Problem: The rest of the code gets cut off at `? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8` because the code includes another AND statement, or '&'. How would I be able to get the full string without the server only returning part of it and cutting the rest off because of '&' included.

Im using this for a project.

Comment: You could encode the GET parameter properly?

Comment: So right now it looks like this

app.get('/bot/upload', (req, res) => {
const code = req.query.code;
  console.log(code)
});

Comment: `upload?code=function uuidv4()`  ***nodejs express server***  You do know that this is a massive security risk?.  And the fact you don't know how to escape the code, worries me even more.. :)

Comment: You are passing JavaScript as a GET request? YIKES

Comment: Ok, but you don't encode the parameter.

Comment: LOL, just noticed the users name ***ScriptSecure Services***, I think he's having a giggle..

Comment: www.example.com/bot/upload?code=function%20uuidv4()%20%7B%20return%20'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(%2F%5Bxy%5D%2Fg%2C%20function(c)%20%7B%20var%20r%20%3D%20Math.random()%20*%2016%20%7C%200%2C%20v%20%3D%20c%20%3D%3D%20'x'%20%3F%20r%20%3A%20(r%20%26%200x3%20%7C%200x8)%3B%20return%20v.toString(16)%3B%20%7D)%3B%20%7D%20console.log(uuidv4())